# JavaFX stop MediaPlayer when window is closed

Tags: javafx

I have this window here:

```
JFrame rainbow = new JFrame();
                rainbow.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
                rainbow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                rainbow.setTitle("RaInBoW");
                rainbow.setResizable(false);
                rainbow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                Media rainbowMusic = new Media("file:///C:/Users/Julius/Downloads/rainbowMusic.mp3");
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(rainbowMusic);
                mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
                rainbow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
                Draw d = new Draw();
                rainbow.add(d);
                rainbow.setVisible(true);
```

Is there a way to stop the MediaPlayer from playing music after closing the JFrame? If yes, could you please tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a close listener to your JFrame like so

```
rainbow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
     // runs whenever the user tries to close the fram
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
});
```

This will pause the media player whenever the frame is closed

Comment: @Julius If _Austin_'s answer solved the issue you were having you should accept it :)

Comment: How is it not working, is there a error or is nothing happening? Please give more details.